# Check for invalid triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there an automated/scripted way to check whether there are any invalid triggers in a database?  Invalid meaning column type mismatches etc.

Comment: Can you show an example of a column type mismatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract and modify the scripts for the triggers and catch exceptions on executing ALTER statements.

```
SELECT ID, Name
     , REPLACE(SQL, 'CREATE TRIGGER', 'ALTER TRIGGER') 
       + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO'  as SQL 
FROM
(                             
SELECT ID,name , SQL = STUFF( (SELECT ' ' + CAST(Text as varchar(max))
                                FROM sys.Syscomments c 
                                WHERE c.id =s.ID 
                                ORDER BY  colid
                                FOR XML PATH(''), type
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                            , 1, 1, '')
FROM sys.sysobjects AS s
WHERE xtype = 'P'
) x
```

Comment: This is is what I was looking for, thanks.  I added small changes, a "go" statement and code to remove the &#x0D; characters, to make the output valid.